# spring boot failed to start the application, database url not specified

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am a beginner in spring, and learning the spring batch basics.

Based on initial training I am able to start the application using a Map based JobRepository by using the below annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Now I am trying to use the local postgresql (NOT using JPA).

But it fails with below error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

Config files are as below:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello-world</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5100/helloworld
spring.datasource.username=someuser
spring.datasource.password=somepasswd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
# Added below 2 based on some other stackoverflow searches
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

Please note I don't want to use JPA, hence not provided the dependency in pom.xml.

Main class:

```
package io.spring.batch;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried to compile, recompile, invalidate caches and restart (intellij) but it seems my application.properties is not read at all.

Local postgres is working, able to connect it via client (DBeaver/pgadmin) and command line.

Can't we run it without specifying JPA dependencies?
If we can, what is wrong in above?

Attaching the snapshot of project structure and error.
[image]

Comment: did you see any log like this in your console: "Loaded config file 'file:/somewhere in your local path/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)" . at least you can ensure that the right applicaiton.properties are loaded...

Comment: Please use `@EnableBatchProcessing` on `HelloWorldApplication` ? Also please make sure project is building correctly

Comment: `Can't we run it without specifying JPA dependencies?`: yes, jpa is not required. `Failed to determine a suitable driver class`: are you sure the driver jar is in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

use

```
   spring.datasource.platform=postgres
```